# AqKanji2Koeのサンプルをコンパイルできない

Tags: c++, clang

コンパイル:

```
# g++ -I./lib64 -o Kanji2KoeCmd samples/Kanji2KoeCmd.cpp -lAqKanji2Koe
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAqKanji2Koe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

追加情報

```
# ldconfig -p | grep AqKanji2Koe
    libAqKanji2Koe.so.4 (libc6,AArch64) => /usr/lib64/libAqKanji2Koe.so.4
    libAqKanji2Koe.so (libc6,AArch64) => /usr/lib64/libAqKanji2Koe.so
```

シンボリックリンクはあります。
https://www.a-quest.com/archive/manual/aqk2k_lnx_man.pdf に書いてある手順通りにやりました。

Comment: ソースファイル `Kanji2KoeCmd.cpp` は何処にあるのか。たぶん Linuxと思われるが何の環境なのか (CPU含め … コンパイルするのなら特に)。その手の情報質問に記したほうがよいでしょう。(あと clangになってるけど g++ ？)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manual/aqk2k_lnx_man.pdf ということなので [言語処理エンジン AqKanji2Koe](https://www.a-quest.com/products/aqkanji2koe.html) の "AqKanji2Koe-A" 側の Linux版 「Linux x86/x86_64 共有ライブラリ(so形式)」なのでしょう。

- エンジン仕様: CPU … Arm11, Cortex-A, 各種Intel CPU

ということだけど, パッケージ製品ラインアップには上記のように「Linux **x86/x86_64** 共有ライブラリ(so形式)」と記されているので, 製品版なら？ 各種 CPU用のライブラリーが提供されるのかソースが提供されるのか, なのかも？
少なくともダウンロードページにある AquesTalk2 の Linux版では, **x86/x86_64** 用の soしか入ってない

しかし `ldconfig -p` の情報見る限り, 質問者さんの環境は **AArch64** のようです

- x86/x86_64 環境で(構築し)コンパイルしてみる
- 評価版に AArch64 は無いのか問い合わせる, もしくは製品版なら付いているのか問い合わせてみる

などでしょうか